# How to calculate the least squares estimator

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, least-squares, parameter-estimation

We have a complex samples y¯^(1) that are modeled by a known real vector a = [a1,..., an]^T
multiplied by an unknown complex scalar α: y¯(1) ≈ a¯ . α

What would be a least squares estimator for α?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written down the optimization problem that defines the least squares estimator?

Comment: So far I just assumed α is like a (m + n.Xi) and I'm trying to find the minimum m and n like to fit like a line. Sorry my calculus background is rusted a bit. Not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I'm not sure if my comment above is correct. Don't count on it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_j = y'_j + i y''_j$ be the complex samples.
The least squares optimization problem is minimizing
$$f(u, v) := \sum_{j=1}^n |(y'_j + iy''_j) - \underbrace{(u+iv)}_{=:\alpha}a_j|^2
= \sum_{j=1}^n (y'_j-ua_j)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n (y''_j - va_j)^2.$$

Taking the partial derivatives with respect to $u$ and $v$ and setting each to zero will give you an expression for the optimal $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thanks. But is this what the OP is exactly asing? Where is alpha? And we didn't use u and v.

Comment: @TinaJ In your comment you mentioned "$\alpha$ is like $m + n\cdot i$"; I just used $u+iv$ instead.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if my comment was correct. Just threw a random assumption. Is your answer fully correct?

Comment: @TinaJ No I'm not sure. Maybe you should let us know what you understand about the problem? Do you know how "least squares estimator for $\alpha$" is defined in your problem? You mentioned "find the minimum $m$ and $n$"; what exactly are you minimizing? etc.

Comment: The main post is what I have. The comment is just my understanding of the problem. Don't count on it.